# Using Anaconda python as default python - csh shell

Tags: linux, bash, shell, python, path

Newly assigned server uses `csh shell`, I have never used `csh` before.

I tried to path to `anaconda/bin` in the `.cshrc`

but if I query `which python` it still returns `usr/bin/python`

It does not even work temporarily. I tried appending path to `anaconda/bin` using `set path=($path /path/to/anaconda/bin)`, and after this $PATH indeed shows path to `anaconda/bin` but if I run `which python` answer is still `/usr/bin/python`

I am never going to use the default python that came with the Ubuntu, so rather than a temporary, I am more interested in a permanent solution. I added the anaconda path to the `.cshrc`, it populated correctly after I started a new session , but no success with starting anaconda python.

I do not want to go through the pain of `cd`ing to the anaconda/bin directory every time to start the python.

Comment: "I tried appending path" You need to add it to the *front* of the path not the end ...

Comment: @DavidPostill, that was very dumb of me, please write it as an answer and I'll accept.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### I tried appending path to anaconda/bin using `set path=($path /path/to/anaconda/bin)`

The path is searched from left to right.

You need to add it to the **front** of the path not the end so `csh` finds Anaconda python before `\usr\bin\python`:

```
set path=(/path/to/anaconda/bin $path)
```